# Azure Triggered Webjob - Detecting when webjob stops

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am developing a triggered webjob that use [TimerTrigger](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extensible-triggers-and-binders-with-azure-webjobs-sdk-1-1-0-alpha1/).

Before the webjob stops, I need to dispose some objects but I don't know how to trigger the "webjob stop".

Having a `NoAutomaticTrigger` function, I know that I can use the [WebJobsShutdownWatcher](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/WebjobsShutdownWatcher.cs) class to handle when the webjob is stopping but with a triggered job I need some help...

I had a look at [Extensible Triggers and Binders with Azure WebJobs SDK 1.1.0-alpha1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extensible-triggers-and-binders-with-azure-webjobs-sdk-1-1-0-alpha1/).

Is it a good idea to create a custom trigger (StopTrigger) that used the `WebJobsShutdownWatcher` class to fire action before the webjob stops ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok The answer was in the question :

Yes I can use the [WebJobsShutdownWatcher](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/WebjobsShutdownWatcher.cs) class because it has a `Register` function that is called when the cancellation token is canceled, in other words when the webjob is stopping.

```
static void Main()
{
    var cancellationToken = new WebJobsShutdownWatcher().Token;
    cancellationToken.Register(() =>
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Do whatever you want before the webjob is stopped...");
    });

    var host = new JobHost();
    // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

**EDIT** (Based on Matthew comment):

If you use Triggered functions,  you can add a `CancellationToken` parameter to your function signatures. The runtime will cancel that token when the host is shutting down automatically, allowing your function to receive the notification.

```
public static void QueueFunction(
        [QueueTrigger("QueueName")] string message,
        TextWriter log,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
    if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can use `WebJobsShutdownWatcher` at the host level if the resources you need to manage are at that scope. Note that you can also add a `CancellationToken` parameter to your function signatures (as in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Functions.cs#L46)). The runtime will cancel that token when the host is shutting down automatically, allowing your function to receive the notification.

Comment: @mathewc, what do you mean by "at the host level" ?.

Comment: I just meant in your Main(). If you want to also be notified inside of currently executing functions, you can use the `CancellationToken` parameter technique.

Comment: really nice example, much more simplier than other one.

Comment: @mathewc is there any way we can use WebJobsShutdownWatcher during the Auto Scale-In when some of my instances gets stopped but not the entire webjob as such

Answer (score 1):

> I was recently trying to figure out how to do this *without* the
>   WebJobs SDK which contains the WebJobShutdownWatcher, this is what I
>   found out.

What the underlying runtime does (and what the `WebJobsShutdownWatcher` referenced above checks), is create a local file at the location specified by the environment variable `%WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE%`. If this file exists, it is essentially the runtime's signal to the webjob that it must shutdown within a configurable wait period (default of 5 seconds for continuous jobs, 30 for triggered jobs), otherwise the runtime will kill the job.

The net effect is, if you are not using the Azure WebJobs SDK, which contains the [WebJobsShutdownWatcher](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/WebjobsShutdownWatcher.cs) as described above, you can still achieve graceful shutdown of your Azure Web Job by monitoring for the shutdown file on an interval shorter than the configured wait period.

Additional details, including how to configure the wait period, are described here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#graceful-shutdown